# Android&Google Maps: My app is changing maps when maps activity is running

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have made an app that collects data from a portable sensor. Data is sent from sensor over a TCP connection every 2 minutes. Every time the sensor sends data a marker is placed on the map and the data is displayed inside the info window. This is done inside `OnLocationChanged()`. Here I also store snippet,title and position inside ArrayLists so I can replace the markers when pausing and stopping the activity.

When I press the back button and start the activity again `addMapPoints()` is called which restores the old markers, which works fine. Then when the sensor sends data I enter `OnLocationChanged()`. The markerOptions are created but when I am add marker to the map `mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)`nothing shows on the map.

After doing some debugging I can see that after pressing the back button and starting the activity again the ID of my Google Map inside `OnLocationChanged()` is different from inside `addMapPoints()`. So the map which I am adding markers to is different from the one showing on the screen. One solution to this would maybe be setting my Google Map as static, are there any  consequences to this? What would otherwise be a soultion?

Here is my code.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
{

public GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
private int co_mV;
private int no2_mV;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private boolean initiateApp;
String currentTime;


TcpClient mTcpClient;
ArrayList<Marker> markerArrayList;
static  ArrayList<Double> markerLat = new ArrayList<>();
static  ArrayList<Double> markerLng = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<String> markerSnippet = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<String> markerTitle = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    initiateApp = true;
    markerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    markerArrayList.clear();
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();

        }
    }
    else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }

    if (markerLat != null) {
        addMapPoints();
    }

    }


/* Here we create the infoWindow **/
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    getNewLocation();
    if (!TcpConnected) {
        new ConnectTask().execute("");
    }
}


public void newData(JSONObject d) {
    try {
        co_mV = d.getInt("co_mV");
        no2_mV = d.getInt("no2_mV");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    getNewLocation();
}

public void getTime() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(cal.getTime());

}

public void getNewLocation() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

public void addMapPoints() {
    markerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < markerLat.size(); i++) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(markerLat.get(i), markerLng.get(i));
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(markerTitle.get(i));
        markerOptions.snippet(markerSnippet.get(i));
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        markerArrayList.add(marker);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {




   /* if (markerArrayList.size()>1) {
        if(location.distanceTo(mLastLocation) < 30) {
            markerArrayList.get(markerArrayList.size()-1).remove();
            markerArrayList.remove(markerArrayList.size()-1);
            markerSnippet.remove(markerSnippet.size()-1);
            markerTitle.remove(markerTitle.size()-1);
            markerLat.remove(markerTitle.size()-1);
            markerLng.remove(markerTitle.size()-1);
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Reading to close to last reading, replaces last reading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    */


    if (markerArrayList.size() == 8) {
        markerArrayList.get(0).remove();
        markerArrayList.remove(0);
        markerSnippet.remove(0);
        markerTitle.remove(0);
        markerLat.remove(0);
        markerLng.remove(0);
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

if (co_mV != 0) {
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(latLng);
markerLat.add(location.getLatitude());
markerLng.add(location.getLongitude());
markerOptions.title("Time of reading: " + currentTime);
markerTitle.add("Time of reading: " + currentTime);
markerOptions.snippet("co: " + String.valueOf(co_mV) + " mV, " + "no2: " + String.valueOf(no2_mV) + " mV");
markerSnippet.add("co: " + String.valueOf(co_mV) + " mV, " + "no2: " + String.valueOf(no2_mV) + " mV");
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
markerArrayList.add(mCurrLocationMarker);
}



    mLastLocation = location;


    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));


    //move map camera

    if(initiateApp){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
    }

    boolean contains = mMap.getProjection()
            .getVisibleRegion()
            .latLngBounds
            .contains(latLng);

    if(!contains){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

    initiateApp = false;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}

public JSONObject getNewJSON(JSONObject json) {
    try {

        int humidity = json.getInt("humidity_ppm");
        int pressure = json.getInt("pressure_Pa");
        int noise = json.getInt("noise_dB");
        double lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

       JSONObject c = new JSONObject();
        c.put("time",time);
        c.put("lat",lat);
        c.put("long",lng);
        c.put("humidity",humidity);
        c.put("pressure",pressure);
        c.put("noise_dB",noise);
        return c;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return null;
}


public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {

    @Override
    protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object
        mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);


        try {
            JSONObject parser = new JSONObject(values[0]);
            JSONObject d = parser.getJSONObject("d");
            JSONObject cloudData = getNewJSON(d);

            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                newData(d);
                getTime();
            }

            System.out.println(cloudData);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //process server response here....
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you are done with getting your location in the last line of your `onLocationChanged` just add this line

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationListener);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Do you mean at the end of the method? After adding markers and everything?

Comment: I tried entering LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);. But it skips that line.

Comment: that is unexpected

Comment: after which line did you add it

Comment: I added it at the end of the method. Then I tried at the end of the (co_mV != 0) loop.

Comment: try adding in at the first line of the function

Comment: I made the map static instead, this solved the problem. Thank you for the help